# Remove one character from a word in an array PHP - only one word displays

Tags: php, arrays, substr

In the "no first characters" part only the last element of the array displays, not sure why. Need the whole array to display. Could someone suggest anything?
Should I leave the foreach loop there or use something else to do the task? 
Just need the first letter of each random word of the array to be removed.

```
function generate($length)
{



$a1 = str_split('0123456789');
$a2 = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'); 
$a3 = str_split('!#$');

$result = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) 
    {
        $values = array_merge($a1,$a2,$a3);
        $x = rand(0, count($values)-1);
        $result .= $values[$x];//taking one symbol  
    }

        return $result;
}

  $array = array();
  $count = 4; // number of elements
  $length = 5;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $array[] = generate($length);

    }

echo '<br>';

echo 'Original array: ' , '<pre>';
    print_r($array);

echo '</pre>', '<br>';

echo 'Sorted: ';
    sort($array);
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);

echo '</pre>' ,'<br>';

echo 'No first characters: ';
     foreach($array as $word)
     {
        $array = substr($word,1); 

     }

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);

echo '</pre>' ,'<br>';
```

Comment: Simpler https://3v4l.org/jWZJe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove a letter from each word, then why do you rewrite `$array`? Use simple loop with `&` which is passing variable by reference:

```
foreach($array as &$word)
{
    $word = substr($word,1); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Honestly, forgot this was even an option.

Comment: Be very careful when using references (`&`) and `foreach` loops: see the Big Red Warning on http://php.net/foreach for details. The best practice is to not use references for this purpose. Instead, use the array key (e.g.  `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { $array[$key] = 'new value'; }`) or, if you do use references, [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) the variable after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

The best and short method;

```
echo 'No first characters: ';
  $array = array_map(function($word){ return substr($word,1); }, $array);
```